# import modules in nodejs routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, node-modules

I have declared socket.io in index.js file, And I would pass soket object to route module.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var routes = require('./routes/routes')(io);

const dbb = mongoose.connect("mongodb://xxx:xxx@ds137600.mlab.com:37600/tasksdb");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

app.use('/', routes);
var server= app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

**routes.js**

```
var express = require("express"); // call express
var taskSchema = require("../models/taskModel");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router

router
    .route("/tasks")
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        ....
    });
router
    .route("/tasks")
    .get(function (req, res) {
        ....
    });
module.exports = router;
```

How can I transfert it to routes.js?  what are the different ways to do it ? I still not well understanding how modules works

Answer (score 0):

For server:

```
const app = express();

app.use(logger('tiny'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowed_header.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, gutsyJwt, Accept'
  );
  next();
});

app.io = require('socket.io')({
  origins: ['*:*'],
});

require('./routes')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

Then in route:

```
module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/bar', (req, res) =>
   fooController.bar(req, res, app.io)
  );
};
```

Then in controller:

```
module.exports = {
  bar(req, res, io) {
    io.emit('message', req.body.message);
    res.status(200).send({msg: 'Message broadcasted!'});
  },
};
```

In this post, it is asking the similar question as well if you need more reference.
[ExpressJS how do I pass objects with state (eg. connections)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258113/expressjs-how-do-i-pass-objects-with-state-eg-connections?rq=1)

Comment: If you can explain more the code ( specially require ('./routes')(app); ) that would be great.

Comment: The route file isn't necessary, some people prefer just to leave all the routes inside of the `app` folder. For me, I like the separation between them. That is just importing the routes from the route folder, and pass in the app as the prop. I edited the route a bit.